rateLimitExceeded for ML.GENERATE_TEXT even after increasing the quota
I'm receiving the error

Exceeded rate limits: too many concurrent queries that use ML.GENERATE_TEXT table-valued function for this project.

Am I missing something? What could I do? Thanks!


The interesting thing is that this error continues after increasing the quota. In addition, it seems that we are far from the limit and also in the usage chart it shows that the limit wasn't passed.

